# execute a shell script in remote machine from a shell script in local machine

Tags: shell

how a shell script can be executed in a remote machine (sitting on the local machine), with some parameter, which I want to pass from local machine.

I have tried the option `ssh $remote_machine bash < script_for_remote_machine.sh $SRC_PATH $TGT_PATH $FILE_DT $bigsql_schema` where `$SRC_PATH` and `$TGT_PATH` are some directories in remote machine. But I am getting error like below in the log

```
+ ssh remote_machine bash /remote_dir1 /remotedir2 20151016 AUDIT
/remote_dir1: /remotedir2: is a directory
+ RETURN_CODE=126
+ '[' 126 -eq 0 ']'
```

Comment: What does the (remote) script try to do with its first argument?

Comment: Seeing the code for both scripts would help us debug the error message.

Comment: `ssh remote_machine bash -c "/remote_dir1 /remotedir2 20151016 AUDIT"` (presuming your `/remote_dir1` is the name of the script you want to execute -- funny name for a script)

Comment: no script name is something different. Here I have just changed the name. What I have tried is `ssh $mgmt_node bash < audit_executable_commands.sh $SRC_PATH $TGT_PATH $FILE_DT $bigsql_schema`

Comment: I have changed as suggested `ssh $mgmt_node bash -c  "audit_executable_commands.sh $SRC_PATH $TGT_PATH $FILE_DT $bigsql_schema"` but getting error `+ ssh box01.devdata.company.com bash -c 'audit_executable_commands.sh /home/bigsql/sqllib/security/auditdata /home/bigsql/sqllib/security/auditdata 20151016 AUDIT'
/home/bigsql/sqllib/security/auditdata: audit_executable_commands.sh: command not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved first by copying all the files in remote machine and executing in the remote machine like below:

```html
scp audit_executable_commands.sh $bigsql_user@$mgmt_node:/home/$bigsql_user
scp audit_record_loading_00.parm $bigsql_user@$mgmt_node:/home/$bigsql_user
ssh $mgmt_node bash < audit_executable_commands.sh
```

where `audit_executable_commands.sh` is the remote script in my case. Now I also want to pass the parameters, that I resolved through a parameter file. I am also copying the parameter file `audit_record_loading_00.parm` in the remote machine and then getting the parameter values in the remote machine while executing a line like `. $cur_dir/audit_record_loading_00.parm` from `audit_executable_commands.sh`